# How to run my dispatch method firstly and stop to change redux state and then call componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my component:

```js
class PreCreate extends Component {

  handleStartBtn = e => {
    this.props.createSurvey(name);
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.currentSurvey !== this.props.currentSurvey) {
      const cookies = new Cookies();
      cookies.set("assignments", `EHS_${this.props.currentSurvey.uuid}`, {
        path: "/"
      });
    }
    this.props.history.push("/polling");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleStartBtn}>
              Start
            </Button>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentSurvey: state.survey.currentSurvey
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    createSurvey: name => dispatch(createSurvey(name))
  };
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps ,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(PreCreate)
);
```

createSurvey method is a dispatcher located in my Redux actions its look like below:

```js
export const surveySuccess = survey => {
  return {
    type: actionType.SURVEY_SUCCESS,
    currentSurvey: survey
  };
};

export const createSurvey = name => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(surveyStart());
    axios({
      method: "post",
      data: {
        name: name
      },
      url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/survey/`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        const survey = res.data;
        dispatch(surveySuccess(survey));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch(surveyFail(err));
      });
  };
};
```

My problem is when handleStartBtn method starts to run and createSurvey method is called it goes to   createSurvey method which is located in my Redux actions successfully but it seems to the operation related to sending my data by Axis will be postponed until calling componentDidUpdate have been finished. it goes to componentDidUpdate without changing state that i expected to change.It's ridiculous after doing operations located in componentDidUpdate it runs the server side operations and hits Redux states.

Comment: It is not clear how you expect your code to behave. Your axios request is not postponded it is just async. Code execution will continue your redux store will update (as will your components that consume it) and as soon as the response is available it will update again. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: @trixn The only thing i want is whenever my program run componentDidUpdate` codes my server side operations which they do by Redux action had been completed and i can access to currentSurvey object

Comment: Then you need to remove or move your `dispatch(surveyStart())` call because it triggers an update of the redux store prior to the time your request has finished. Either you remove it entirely or you call it in the `.then()` handler that is called when your request has finished.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is not tied in any way to axios. It will run whenever the props or state of the component changes. And that e.g. happens when you dispatch an action that alters the redux store. But you dispatch it **before** your request has finished.

Comment: @trixn i removed the dispatch(surveyStart()) completely but my problem still remained it first call createSurvey action then back to componentDidUpdate without changing the states then call surveySuccess which is located in my Redux actions calls.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is only called if your state did update. I can't see how that can happen if you removed `dispatch(surveyStart())` because this is the only action that might have triggered an update prior to your request completing.